# array manipulation: wellreader

Tags: java, arrays

I am also a student who's still on the process of learning Java programming (using jcreator).
Here's my prob. 
Our topic is array manipulation and below is the example that was given to us by our professor.

I don't know why the wellreader is always returning an error "cannot resolve symbol variable wellreader".

```
public class upavon
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int [] sizes = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

        System.out.print("number ... ");
        int month = (int) **wellreader.read_number();**
        if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        {
            System.out.println ("Not a valid month number");
        } else 
        {
            System.out.print("That month has ");
            System.out.print(sizes[month-1]);
            System.out.println(" days");
        }

        System.out.print("Length of sizes array: ");
        System.out.println(sizes.length);

        int day = month;
        sizes = new int[7];

        for (int k=0;k<7;k++)
            sizes[k]=24;

        if (day < 1 || day > 7)
        {
            System.out.println("Not a valid day number");
        } else 
        {
            System.out.print("That day has ");
            System.out.print(sizes[day-1]);
            System.out.println(" hours");
        }

        System.out.print("Length of sizes array: ");
        System.out.println(sizes.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the variable `wellreader` declared? From the code you've submitted, the compiler is right.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why the wellreader is always returning
>   an error "cannot resolve symbol variable wellreader".

The `wellreader` is not returning this error, the compiler is returning it.
Probably your professor has another class `Wellreader` and `wellreader`
is an instance/object of this class. You don't have the class `Wellreader`
and you don't have the definition of the variable `wellreader`. So the
compiler complains which is normal.